# Getting Teams Calls returns Application not registered in our store

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm struggling with Microsft Graph. I want to fetch Teams Calls from the graph API to throw them against our ticket software. Sounds easy at first. And I think it is but I don't get why it won't work.

Edit:
Just a heads up. I ended up using the Microsoft Graph subscription model.

To be clear, I don't want to create a teams app, I just want to fetch Teams Calls/Meetings.

This is my code (removed ID's for obvious reasons):

```
class Program
{
    // (Company IDs)
    static string tenantId = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx";
    static string servicePrincipal = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx";
    static string servicePrincipalKey = "keyyyyy";

    // Admin consent if not already applied
    // https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/adminconsent?client_id=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx&state=randomState
    // In my case admin consent was given via azure portal for the following permissions:
    // Yes, it's too much. But I'm desperate...
    /* Microsoft Graph (10)
        CallRecords.Read.All
        Calls.AccessMedia.All
        ChannelMessage.Read.All
        Chat.Read.All
        IdentityProvider.Read.All
        OnlineMeetings.Read.All
        TeamsActivity.Read.All
        TeamsApp.Read.All
        User.Read.All 
    */

    static string[] scopes = {
        "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default",
        //"https://graph.microsoft.com/CallRecords.Read.All" // doesn't work
        //"https://graph.microsoft.com/TeamsApp.Read.All" // doesn't work
        //"https://graph.microsoft.com/Chat.ReadWrite.All" // doesn't work
    };
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {

        var authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" + "/v2.0";

        var clientConf = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(servicePrincipal)
            .WithAuthority(authority, true)
            .WithClientSecret(servicePrincipalKey)
            .Build();

        GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async(requestMessage) =>
        {
            var authResult = await clientConf
                .AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
                .ExecuteAsync();
            requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authResult.AccessToken);
        }));

        //_ = graphClient.Teams.Request().GetAsync(); // Debug test

        // Trying to fetch all calls or meetings
        var onlineMeetings = await graphClient
            .Communications.Calls.Request().GetAsync(); // Doesn't work
        //.Users.Request().GetAsync(); // This works!
        //.Communications.OnlineMeetings.Request().GetAsync(); // Doesn't work

        Console.WriteLine(onlineMeetings);
        // If requesting users, this works without issues 
        /*
        var count = 0;
        foreach (var user in onlineMeetings) {
            Console.WriteLine(count);
            Console.WriteLine(user.UserPrincipalName);
            count++;
        }
        */

    }
}
```

When I run this mess I get the follwing error:

```
"Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException in System.Private.CoreLib.dll"
Code: UnknownError
{
  "errorCode":"7503",
   "message":"`**Application is not registered in our store.**`",
   "instanceAnnotations":[]
}
```

Does anyone have an idea on what I'm doing wrong here?

**Stacktrace**

```
ClientRequestId: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'
    at Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.<SendAsync>d__18.MoveNext()
    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
    at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.<SendRequestAsync>d__35.MoveNext()
    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
    at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.<SendAsync>d__31`1.MoveNext()
    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
    at Microsoft.Graph.CloudCommunicationsCallsCollectionRequest.<GetAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
    at Teams_Graph.Program.<Main>d__4.MoveNext() in c:\Users\<user.name>\Documents\Development\C#\Teams-Graph\Program.cs: Line50
```

Answer (score 3):

There isn't an API for [listing all Calls or Meetings](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/5394) in an organization. You need to specify the `id` of the Call/Meeting you want:

```
var Calls = await graphClient
    .Communications
    .Calls["{call id}"]
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();

var onelineMeeting = await graphClient
    .Communications
    .OnlineMeetings["{meeting id"]
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks! I need to get the call IDs first though. How would I know them if I can't fetch at least the IDs of all calls?

Comment: The assumption is that you either initiated or captured the call via the API first. It isn't possible to simply jump into "any" call. For what its worth, even if it were to allow this, doing so would likely run afoul of local communication laws and regs.

Comment: I understand the legal issues here. Though, it's the only way to properly implement a call history into our ticket software. Currently skype offers more than enough ways to get the calls. If we are forced to switch to teams in future this is a must have for many systems out there. At least in my humble opinion.
Anyways, thanks for your help so far! I'm in contact with microsofts dev department. For now, they say exactly the same. If it stays this way I'll accept your reply as answer. Edit: Wait. You ARE Microsoft :D. Nice. So there's indeed no other way at the moment?

Comment: I'm responsible for our Edu APIs, so I can't speak to Teams API roadmap but there are still substantial gaps between Skype UCMA and Teams API (although it is has been closing rapidly). That said, depending on your comm architecture and routing, you might be able to achieve what you're looking for by implementing a lightweight IVR for intercepting all incoming calls, storing the metadata, and then redirecting the call to the final destination. You may want to take a look at the [Calling SDK](https://microsoftgraph.github.io/microsoft-graph-comms-samples/docs/) and some of their IVR examples.

Comment: Well, how do I connect this SDK to the Teams client? I don't really want to create another application just for users to make calls. They already use teams.
Can you register the bot to the Azure Tenant so that ALL calls are piped through the bot?