# Microsoft Graph API: How to use Get Call Method?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-graph-cloudcommunications

I'm using the Microsoft Graph API to retrieve information about Microsoft Teams.
Now i want to retrieve information about the call using the method in the documentation below:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/call-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Here is written that i have to use the following url: 
GET /communications/calls/{id}

The thing is that i don't know what is the id i need to use because in the documentation is not specified.
I try to use the group id, channel id and personal id of Teams but none of them works. Somebody knows how to use this method?

Thanks

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Properties of call resource type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/call?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties), `id` is the **call id**. Read-only.

When you [create a call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-calls?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), you will get an `id` in the response. see the [response sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-calls?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#response-1).

When you need to get the call, just put this id value into `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/communications/calls/{id}`.

Comment: Hi, but if a have a call without using the method "create a call". I create it in Microsoft Teams, how can i reach the "call id"?

Comment: @PieroGiacalone Get call should be used in pair with Create call. After you get the ID through the Microsoft Graph API, use Get call to get the content of the call. If you didn’t know the ID first, It isn't possible to simply jump into "any" call. See a similar post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60222762/getting-teams-calls-returns-application-not-registered-in-our-store.

Comment: @PieroGiacalone Do you have any further concerns about this issue?

Comment: @AllenWu what I think Piero is asking  (and what I would like to know as well) is, let's say I don't want to programmatically "create a call" I just want to use the teams app to call someone, how can the call ID be retrieved other than subscribing to a change notification